# Store result of an operations in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command in bash that returns the locale of an IP address stored in variable `$line`. The command looks something like this:

```
geoiplookup -f GeoIP.dat "$line" >> resultFile
```

which will return a result such as "New York, NY".

Now I want to concatenate  the Ip address to the result so it looks something like this:

"215.216.217.218, New York, NY"

So something like:

```
$line +", "+ (geoiplookup -f GeoIP.dat "$line") >>resultFile
```

Can anyone give me the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
echo "$line, $(geoiplookup -f GeoIP.dat "$line")" >> resultFile
```

This relies on the backtick operator of bash `$(...)` which executes a command and captures its output. So in the above line, bash will execute `geoiplookup -f GeoIP.dat "$line"` and put its output in place of the `$(...)` part.

Answer (score 1):

The title of this question is leading you down the wrong path.  You do not need to store the output at all.  Just write everything to the output file in the desired order:

```
{ printf "%s, " "$line"; geoiplookup -f GeoIP.dat "$line"; } >> resultFile
```